# Regexp of "it does NOT start with KEYWORD1"

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Consider a tee export of a MySQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
     *
     *
     *
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I would like to process this mysqlqtee.txt file through sed or perl, filtering the actual data rows only.

I can tell sed or perl to: **"Comment out every line starting with the static text of '| AB', please!"**

```
sed -i '.old' 's/\(^\| AB.*\)/#\1/g' mysqlqtee.txt
perl -pi.old -e 's/(^\| AB.*)/#$1/g' mysqlqtee.txt
```

These get me:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY timecode;
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
#| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
     *
     *
     *
#| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
#| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

nicely commenting out all the actual data rows and leave every other line untouched.

What I am so far unable to tell perl or sed is to: **"Comment out every line starting with anything OTHER THAN the static text of '| AB', please!"** 
Which would get me:

```
#SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY timecode;
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
     *
     *
     *
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I don't seem to be able to translate the **"IT DOESN'T START WITH"** part to regexp.
The dual use of ^ meaning NOT and LINE_START at the same time causes trouble.
I can negate the starting letter with `s/^[^\|]/`, but that also leaves the header row out.

I managed to do this in perl, using an `IF` statement.
But it still disturbs me way too much that I couldn't do it with a single `s///g`.
Can this be done that way?

How do I translate the **"IT DOESN'T START WITH"** part to regexp? Either sed or perl solution is fine!

Comment: Is this one useful? http://superuser.com/questions/244723/exclude-some-matches-with-sed

Comment: Yes, it is useful, because it enables me to exclude the header row. But it does not answer the question that's been bugging me.

Comment: Why use a mysql client and grep its output, when you can just connect to the DB directly using the real API?  And, why not tailor your query: `SELECT * from mytable where label1 NOT REGEX '^AB'`?

Comment: I think it's a mistake to base the negated regexp on data that might change i.e. data under `label1` will not always not `AB...` if it is then it's wasted in a database. Better to concentrate on removing headers and footers i.e. anything that's doesn't begin with `|` or begins with `| label1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate a regex with `sed` by putting `!` after it like so:

```
sed -i.old '/^| AB/!s/^/#/' mysqltree.txt
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^| AB/!s/^/#/' mysqltree.txt
#SELECT * FROM mytable;
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Excellent. This use of the negation has eluded me until now.

Comment: I believe this is what I should have done when I was trying to negate the "| AB" inside the regex of the `s//`, like `s/!(^\| AB)/`. But it didn't work. :-)

Comment: `\|` with `sed` is alternation. If you want a literal `|` you don't escape it.

Answer (score 3):

This task is made easy if you use a lookahead. Instead of using a capture group, just assert that the text is, or is not what you seek.

Comment the lines:

```
perl -pi.old -e's/^(?=\| AB)/#/' mysqlqtee.txt
```

Comment all the other lines:

```
perl -pi.old -e's/^(?!\| AB)/#/' mysqlqtee.txt
```

Comment: @TheNail The Nail's comment showed this, but in a slightly different environment and I did not see at the time that it can also be used the way you just demonstrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no negation in regexps, but you have all the power of the whole programming language, so use it:

```
perl -pi.old -e '/(^\| AB.*)/ or $_ = "#$_"' mysqlqtee.txt
```

Comment: Simple, short, elegant, works! I am still figuring out how it translates to English. The regex part says "match all lines starting with '| AB'. If I understand correctly, the `or` has the effect of the English "otherwise", so the rest means "otherwise make the current line begin with a hash-mark". Correct me if I am wrong, please! In this case, it is a very interesting approach I wouldn't have considered.

Comment: correction, there is no negation in *perl's* regex, `sed` can negate just fine

Comment: @SiegeX nonsense. The negation isn't in the regex, but in the sed language, just as with perl.

Comment: I would write this more readably (IMO) as `perl -pi.old -e 's/^/#/ unless /^\| AB/'`. `unless` reads more naturally than `or`, and the capturing parens and the `.*` in the regex are unneeded.

Comment: @hobbs, I use `or` 100 times per script. `unless`? Never used. Every time I encounter `unless`, I have to spend time mentally translating it. Nothing natural about it as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you -

```
sed -i.bak '/^+--/,/^+--/s/^/#/;1s/^/#/' file
           |____________|     |___| 
                 |              |
          This defines a    This identifies
          regex range.       the first line
```

- For our simple substitution we provide two markers. First is a `regex range`. This range suggests that start from a line which starts with `+--` and continue till you find another line like that. For all those lines put a `#` in front of it. As a result, the lines after your SQL query until the beginning of data gets `#` in front of them. Also, since the regex range starts at the very end of file, it starts marking `#`. Since there is no end range encountered there it will mark until the end of file
- The second marker is a line number. Since we want to put `#` in front of your SQL statement, we tell sed that look at the first line and what ever that may be, put a `#` in front of it.

#### InputFile:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
     *
     *
     *
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

#### Test: You can use the `-i option` to backup the original file or redirect the following output to another file.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '/^+--/,/^+--/s/^/#/;1s/^/#/' file
#SELECT * FROM mytable;
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#| label1   | lbl2  | label3   | label4    | lbl5  | lbl6 | label7 |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001596 |  0.161152 |     2 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001404 |  0.162774 |     3 |    1 | a      |
     *
     *
     *
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001286 | 10.941642 |  5999 |    1 | a      |
| ABCDEFGH | YNNYY | 0.001315 | 10.942950 |  6000 |    1 | a      |
#+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+
#9995 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as I need. But I have no idea how it does its job! :-)

Comment: Added the explanation @Keve :)

Comment: Bombastic. Thanks for the explanation! Now it all makes sense. I just have one more question: You guys who come up with these, what do you eat? :-)

Comment: Well, whatever it is you eat, it works magic on the human brain. The generic food I eat (apple, banana, chicken, pork, potato, rice) doesn't have that effect on me. :-)

Comment: OK, I am on fruit loops from today! :-)  Thanks again Jaypal! Your answer was a mind opening.

Answer (score 0):

To match the character '|', use `\|` (a character class `[|]` would also work); to match any character *except* '|', use a negated character class `[^|]`.